# MatLab Simulink C++ Code Generation error with Bus Selector

Tags: matlab, simulink, embedded-coder

I have a Model Predictive Controller for a simulated autonomous vehicle in MatLab. I can currently run simulations using this controller, so I know the model is correct and functional.

I am trying to export this model to C++ code using the Embedded Code App. After getting to this step in the Quick Start:
[Embedded Coder Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KToRm.png)

I get this error:

`Selected signal 'Detections.Time' in the Bus Selector block 'Model/Detections' is invalid since it refers to a bus element within an array of sub-buses. The path to the array of sub-buses is 'Detections'. Please select the appropriate array element using a Selector block before using the Bus Selector block to access an element within the bus.`

I would like to solve this error without manipulating the model. Is this possible?
Currently, my only idea is to add a Selector block before the Bus Selector block. Given that this is a legacy project, and that this model was handed to my team, I do not want to manipulate the model in this way.

Some images of the model componentry are included below.

Thanks for any and all assistance!!!

[Model Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulhgt.png)

[Bus Selector Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRzS6.png)

Comment: Hi. foundObjects match with bus Detections? Or instead you have to choose one array element like suggest the error.